pgAdmin4 in Kubernetes says Refused to execute script, strict MIME type checking is enabled?
I am trying to run pgAdmin4 in Kubernetes but i always get "Refused to execute script, strict MIME type checking is enabled?" error and other errors.

According to strict MIME type checking is enabled issue with PGAdmin in Azure application gateway and https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues/7412 there should be a problem with azure.
The kubernetes is running in AKS so I guess it is als my problem because it is running locally without problems.
Here is the kubernetes statefullset:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: pgadmin
  namespace: {{ NAMESPACE_NAME }}
spec:
  serviceName: pgadmin-service
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  replicas: 1
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pgadmin
      role: database
  template:
    metadata:
      name: my-deployment
      labels:
        app: pgadmin
        role: database
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      initContainers:
        - name: create-readonly-user
          image: "{{ POSTGRES_IMAGE }}"
          imagePullPolicy: "Always"
          env:
            - name: CONNECTION_STRING
              value: "{{ CONNECTION_STRING}}"
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: pgadmin-secret
                  key: postgres-readonly-username
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: pgadmin-secret
                  key: postgres-readonly-password
          command: [ "/bin/bash" ]
          args:
            - -c
            - >
              psql "${CONNECTION_STRING:?}" -c "CREATE ROLE ${POSTGRES_USER:?} WITH LOGIN PASSWORD '${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:?}'"
              psql "${CONNECTION_STRING:?}" -c "GRANT pg_read_all_data TO ${POSTGRES_USER:?}"
      containers:
        - name: pgadmin
          image: dpage/pgadmin4:8.13.0
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 0
            runAsGroup: 0
          env:
            - name: PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: pgadmin-secret
                  key: pgadmin-default-email
            - name: PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: pgadmin-secret
                  key: pgadmin-default-password
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: pgadmin-secret
                  key: postgres-readonly-username
            # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64394628/csrf-token-is-missing-error-in-docker-pgadmin
            - name: PGADMIN_CONFIG_WTF_CSRF_CHECK_DEFAULT
              value: "False"
            - name: PGADMIN_CONFIG_WTF_CSRF_ENABLED
              value: "False"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: {{ PGADMIN_CONTAINER_PORT }}
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: pgadmin-data
              mountPath: /var/lib/pgadmin
            - name: servers-file
              mountPath: /conf
            - name: cfg-file
              mountPath: /cfg
          lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                # sh: envsubst: command not found in container image
                command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sed \"s/<<<POSTGRES_USER>>>/${POSTGRES_USER}/g\" /conf/servers.json > /pgadmin4/servers.json && cp -v /cfg/config_local.py /pgadmin4/config_local.py && ls -lisah /pgadmin4 && cat /pgadmin4/config_local.py"]
      volumes:
        - name: servers-file
          configMap:
            name: pgadmin-configmap-servers-file
            items:
              - key: "servers.json"
                path: "servers.json"
        - name: cfg-file
          configMap:
            name: pgadmin-configmap-cfg-file
            items:
              - key: "config_local.py"
                path: "config_local.py"
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: pgadmin-data
      spec:
        accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 3Gi

And here is the configmap for the configfile:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: pgadmin-configmap-cfg-file
  namespace: {{ NAMESPACE_NAME }}
  labels:
    app: postgres
data:
  "config_local.py": |
    X_CONTENT_TYPE_OPTIONS = ""
    ENHANCED_COOKIE_PROTECTION = False
    X_XSS_PROTECTION = "0"

The init container is working fine. It creates the user for pgAdmin. Also the servers file which is used is working. I copy the servers file to /pgadmin4/servers.json. I also copy the config_local.py is this directory because I found the the config.py in this directory. The documentation in https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/config_py.html means this file should maybe moved to /etc/pgadmin/config_system.py but as I understand this is only for the config_system.py and not the config_local.py.
According to strict MIME type checking is enabled issue with PGAdmin in Azure application gateway and https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues/7412 I created the config file with the content which is needed to fix the issue in Azure but I still have the error.
I am not sure if the config file is working because I dont have access rights to the kubernetes container to check if the file exists and also if it in the right place so I add an option called CHECK_EMAIL_DELIVERABILITY = True but the boot of the pgAdmin container still says:
│ pgadmin email config is {'CHECK_EMAIL_DELIVERABILITY': False, 'ALLOW_SPECIAL_EMAIL_DOMAINS': []}                           │
│ pgadmin NOTE: Configuring authentication for SERVER mode.                                                                  │
│ pgadmin                                                                                                                    │
│ pgadmin pgAdmin 4 - Application Initialisation                                                                             │
│ pgadmin ======================================                                                                             │
│ pgadmin                                                                                                                    │
│ pgadmin ----------                                                                                                         │
│ pgadmin Loading servers with:   

Am I doing something wrong? I try to print the file and directory content with post start cycle command but I dont see the output. Any tipps or tricks to debug?
